# Obtain an expression for the resultant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given

\begin{align}
y_1 & = 3\sin\omega t \\
y_2 & = 8\sin(\omega t+\frac\pi 9)
\end{align}

Obtain an expression for $y_R = y_1 + y_2$ by drawing and by calculation.

Comment: Cheers guys for the edit. Apologies for my poor format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are as lazy as I am (I do not consider that this is a sin !), consider the function
$$f(t)=3 \sin ( \omega t)+8 \sin \left( \omega t +\frac{\pi
   }{9}\right)-a \sin ( \omega t+\varphi )=0$$
$$f(0)=8 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-a \sin (\varphi )=0\tag 1$$
$$f\left(\frac{\pi }{2 \omega }\right)=3+8 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-a \cos (\varphi )=0\tag 2$$ making $$a \sin (\varphi )=8 \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)\tag 3$$
$$a \cos (\varphi )=3+8 \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)\tag 4$$ Square $(3)$ and $(4)$ and add them to get $a^2$. Then, from $3$, get $\varphi$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall that

- $\sin (x+y)=\sin x \cos y+\sin y \cos x$

then

- $\sin(\omega t+\frac\pi 9)=\sin \omega t \cos \frac\pi 9+\sin \frac\pi 9 \cos \omega t$

then recall also the [linear combination formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine_and_cosine) of sine and cosine waves

- $a\sin x+b\cos x=c\cdot\sin(x+\varphi)$